# Yii javascript on page

Tags: javascript, php, yii

In my web-page my Javascript code looks like:

```
$js1 = <<< JS
 function test1() {
 }   
JS;

$js2 = <<< JS
 function test2() {
 }   
JS;

$j3 = <<< JS
 function test3() {
 }   
JS;
```

Using some kind of logic I want to concatenate Javascript like this:

```
if ($something == 1 ){
    $js = $js1.$js2;
}
```

How can I do that properly with Yii rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once you have the cocatenated $js, simply do...

```
<?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('myJS', $js); ?>
```